# How to separate last 4 digits from a line in matlab?

Tags: excel, matlab

I have an excel document and I want to separate the last 4 digits of the column B for every line. Let's say for example the first. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure you want to do that in Excel, but if you don't mind - that simple formula:

```
=VALUE(RIGHT(B1,4))
```

will return what you want (assuming your data starts from 1st row). Autofill the formula down if required. If you want 4 digits returned as `string`, nut number - remove `VALUE(...)` part.

**EDIT:**

As per comment, you need to use this formula:

```
=HEX2DEC(RIGHT(B2,4))
```

Autofill or copy/paste it down the row 554.

Sample file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4mnx5x3h28gv3rs/4DigitsHEX2DEC.xlsx

Comment: to be more specific, my data starts from the 2nd line and goes on until line 554. it is in the row B. the row A isn't of much importance for me. this is an example line: 13:52:04,18,00FFFF00100A0093000001000010034317D4 and I want the last 4 digits: 17D4 which is a hex number. I want to take all this numbers from those 554 lines and take all the hex numbers and convert them in decimal through matlab.